# Can't find any logic how the faulty script works flawlessly?

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script in vba using IE to get the titles of different hotel names from a webpage. The hotel names traverse multiple pages through pagination.

My scraper can keep clicking on the next button successfully while parsing the titles from each page until ther is no more click left to perform. The parser is doing is job just perfect. All I wish to know is a simple logic I've asked below.

My question: How the content of each page is rightly coming through even when I didn't use this `Set Htmldoc = IE.document` line just after the `.click`? When a click is initiated, the scraper goes to a new page with new content. How come it gets updated with new content from each page as my defined `do loop` comes after `with IE` block?

This is the script:

```
Sub GetTitles()
    Const Url As String = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147237-Caribbean-Hotels.html"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Htmldoc As HTMLDocument, post As Object, R&

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Htmldoc = .document
    End With

    Do
        For Each post In Htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("listing") ''how this "Htmldoc" gets updated
            With post.getElementsByClassName("property_title")
                If .Length Then R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
            End With
        Next post

        If Not Htmldoc.querySelector(".standard_pagination span[onclick*='pagination_next']") Is Nothing Then
            Htmldoc.querySelector(".standard_pagination span[onclick*='pagination_next']").Click
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

            ''I didn't use anything like "Set Htmldoc = IE.document" but it still works flawlessly 
        Else:
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is not faulty. Though, you are using it without fully understanding is certainly troublesome.

---

When you do this `Set Htmldoc = .document` you are setting the IE's document for later use.

When you do this `Htmldoc.querySelector(".standard_pagination span[onclick*='pagination_next']").Click` javascript comes in play and **updates** the content of the page (i.e document).

You may believe that the document has changed but its only being updated. In reality,there is no navigation happening at all.

---

Add the following and see how the page/document remains the same, just the content changes.

```
            '/ Url before Next button click
            Debug.Print "Before Click " & Htmldoc.Url
            Htmldoc.querySelector(".standard_pagination span[onclick*='pagination_next']").Click
            '/ Url after Next button click
            Debug.Print "After Click " & Htmldoc.Url
```

---

Since the document, once set remains the same and the updated content has same layout/DOM *(that is how mostly programmers code, most likely all the pages are being rendered using a template*) hence your code works perfectly fine. Net to net for your do loop, nothing changed.

Comment: Yes, it seems you understand what my question was. Provided plus one. I took a guess in the first place that mystery lies here `Set Htmldoc = .document` as the fully qualified line is `Set Htmldoc = IE.document`. So, IE is always there. Thanks @cyboashu for your answer. Let's wait until the bounty expires.

Answer (score 0):

`Set Htmldoc = .document`

gets a pointer to the DOM. When it changes the Htmldoc is pointing at the new content. No need to do a new Set Htmldoc

Comment: Thanks @peakpeak for that information. This is what I wanted to know. However, can you provide me with any link (leading to any documentation) as a proof of concept?

Comment: @Topto It seems like pointers may be unfamiliar to you, given your question. Here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)

Comment: What is a pointer and how does it work is not what my question was. My question was: what is the source of this information `htmldoc gets a pointer to the dom`? Whether `htmldoc` has got that feature (he tried to mean) is what I wish to know?